# How can i share image using pinterest sdk in android?

Tags: android, pinterest

I have installed Pinterest SDK  using [pinterst developer site](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/android/?) in my android studio project and register app in developers account.I can't find out sources that can share the images in developer console.how can I share image just like facebook and twitter using sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I have shared image using below code.

```
private void shareOnPinterest() {
        String sharingText = "Sharing Text";
        String imageUrl = "Image Url";
        String description = "Description";
        String url = String.format(
                "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=%s&media=%s&description=%s",
                urlEncode(sharingText), urlEncode(imageUrl), description);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        filterByPackageName(getActivity(), intent, getString("com.pinterest"));
        startActivity(intent);


    } else {
        Utils.displayDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_somthing_went_wrong));
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!